# How to restore vmdk from two vsan node cluster?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsan

I've setup 2 node cluster vsan and with a witnees host.

I usually run only one node and keep synchronized every night by open another node, after that i let one node in maintance mode and shut it down.

I thought one node can be another's backup. Now one vmdk object on running node have an unrecoverable mistake, can I get this object from another node? and how to do it?

Auto synchroning should be disabled though, and how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the intended use of VMware vSAN. VMware vSAN is designed to provide you with HA storage for VMware cluster and in case of two nodes, that's active-active mirror. You should not turn one of the nodes on and off and turn it to active-passive synchronization.

VMware vSAN does distributed object storage so your VM's vmdk is comprised of two components and a witness distributed between disk groups and hosts.

In other words, you're picking a wrong tool to do the job. If you want backups, use proper backup software like Veeam, Veritas, or any other or if you need DR, there is vSphere Replication.